# Nested list Comparision with format string in python

Tags: python

```
l = ["Youtube", "Instagram", "Facebook"]

a = [
    [
        "{} {}".format(i[2 * j : 2 * j + 1], i[2 * j + 1 : 2 * j + 2])
        for j in range(len(i) // 2)
    ]
    for i in l
]
print(a)
```

This will return

```
[['Y o', 'u t', 'u b'], ['I n', 's t', 'a g', 'r a'], ['F a', 'c e', 'b o', 'o k']]
```

How the above list I can join first character space with the second character, Please tell if i missing anything in the inner array List.

Below is the **output** I want the odd space with even character

```
[['Yuu otb'], ['Isar ntga'], ['Fcbo aeok']]
```

Comment: And you want each of them as a list with one element?

Comment: And you want to discard any final odd letter, correct?  I.e. the "e" in "Youtube" and the "m" in "Instagram"?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You have pretty good code in here, you don't need to join the elements, just modify how the inner part works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could `join` slices of the strings as follows:

```
[[' '.join((s[:-1:2], s[1::2]))] for s in l]
# [['Yuu otb'], ['Isar ntga'], ['Fcbo aeok']]
```

Comment: Slickest solution so far (IMHO).

Comment: @yatu, you are a man, how you think in that way one-liner solution, I really appreciate your solution thanks!

Comment: @yatu the first slice should be `s[::2]` because it will go untill the end of the string, it fails for `l = ["ivvkxq", "ivvkx"]`, So please edit your awswer

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need a double list comp for this.  You can accomplish this by slicing up to the last even element and stepping by 2.

If you want them as single strings in a one-deep list:

```
[f'{x[:2*(len(x)//2):2]} {x[1:2*(len(x)//2):2]}' for x in l]
# returns:
['Yuu otb', 'Isar ntga', 'Fcbo aeok']
```

If you want them 2-deep:

```
[[f'{x[:2*(len(x)//2):2]} {x[1:2*(len(x)//2):2]}'] for x in l]
# returns:
[['Yuu otb'], ['Isar ntga'], ['Fcbo aeok']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with the main structure of your original solution,

```
a = [
    [
        "{} {}".format("".join([i[2 * j : 2 * j + 1] for j in range(len(i) // 2)]),
            "".join([i[2 * j + 1 : 2 * j + 2] for j in range(len(i) // 2)]))
    ]
    for i in l
]
```

Comment: Scott Hunterr,  I agree with your solution will give desire output, but this seems to be take high time complexity as there are 3*for loop

Comment: Time is comparable to your original code; additional loop isn't nested.  Your code did 2 expressions for each `j`; mine does 1 expression for each `j`, twice.

Answer (score 0):

I have combined `zip` and `join`

```
l = ["Youtube", "Instagram", "Facebook"]
a = [["{} {}".format(i[2 * j : 2 * j + 1], i[2 * j + 1 : 2 * j + 2])for j in range(len(i) // 2)]for i in l]
b = [[''.join(x) for x in zip(*i) if ''.join(x).replace(' ', '')] for i in a]
c = [' '.join(i) for i in b]
print(c)
```

Output:

```
['Yuu otb', 'Isar ntga', 'Fcbo aeok']
```